# Snowflake error GsInstance with ID 222673 not in fdb

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got an error "Error - 390410: GsInstance with ID 222673 not in fdb" when trying to run a "CREATE OR REPLACE" command.
I guess that was a temporary issue because this hasn't occurred again, but what does this error mean? Did someone encounter this error and can please help me understand this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to allow someone to emulate your issue and provide feedback, I'm sure someone in the community will be able to comment once they have a bit more clarity into the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend opening a support ticket if your queries are failing and error messages look like "Error - 390410: GsInstance with ID 222673 not in fdb", the ticket should include the Snowflake URL, the queryID of the command, etc...  The more info you give support the more easily they can address the issue.

Getting your query_id can be done using either of the following:

via SQL commands:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

via the webUI:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html

I hope this helps...Rich